# G is homeomorphic to $G/H\times H$

Tags: general-topology, lie-groups, topological-groups, quotient-group

Let G be a topological group and $H\le G$.

Let $\pi: G\to G/H$ be the canonical projection and a continuous $\sigma: G/H\to G$ such that $\pi \circ \sigma = Id$.

Prove that G is  homeomorphic to $G/H\times H$.

I am confused by this question because $\pi$ is a bijective morphism so we should rather have $G\cong G/H$.

Thank you for your help.

### Edit

Thanks to your comments/answers I cleared my confusion. Now if I go back to the original question. Wy is $G$ homeomorphic to  $H\times G/H$.

Factorization theorem gives an isomorphism $G\cong H\times G/H$ because $H=\ker \pi$ and $G/H=\text{Image}(\pi)$.

I don't see how to build this homeomorphism by hand.

Thanks again.

Comment: Why not @ThomasShelby? it has an inverse $\sigma$. Or maybe what's missing is to have also $\sigma \circ \pi = Id$?

Comment: If $G = \Bbb R^2$ under addition, and $H$ is the $x$-axis, then $\pi$ is most definitely not bijective, as $\sigma(G/H)$ is the $y$-axis. Just because $\pi\circ \sigma = Id$, that doesn't mean that $\sigma\circ\pi = Id$.

Comment: Thank you Arthur and Thomas. now I see the issue

Comment: $\sigma$ is a continuous homomorphism?

Comment: yes @HennoBrandsma It is. my mistake I'll edit the question

Comment: The factorization theorem doesn't apply here. I don't see the assumption that $H$ is normal. And since you are looking for a **homeomorphism** instead of topological group isomorphism then I don't think this is an implicit assumption. Also note that what you call the factorization theorem is not true if $G$ is non-abelian.

Comment: @freakish indeed no mention of normality of H in my problem. Why doesn't factorisation here? couldn't we at least factorize by the Relationship $xy^{-1}\in H$? $G/H $ in that case won't be a group but we'll have a bijection $G/H \to \pi(G)$?

Comment: @PerelMan right, you mean factorization as sets via equivalence relation. Yes, that works. But it isn't clear why the topological homeomorphism follows. But note that $H$ is not the kernel of $\pi$. That doesn't make sense when $H$ is not normal.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: Consider $f:G/H\times H\rightarrow G$ defined by $f(x,y)=\sigma(x)y$ and $h:G\rightarrow G/H\times H$ defined by $h(z)=(\pi(z), (\sigma(\pi(z))^{-1}z)$ and show that $f$ is the inverse of $h$.

Comment: I feel like it's similar to the splitting lemma, where we are given a section or a retraction and we can write the middle object as a direct sum. Do we have a more general result in terms of category theory?

Comment: Right It is ill defined

Comment: This answer (now that it's been edited) looks correct to me.

Comment: Except that why $\sigma(\pi(z))^{-1}z\in H$?

Answer (score 4):

If we take $H=\mathbb{Z}$ in $G=(\mathbb{R},+)$ then $G/{H} \simeq S^1$, the unit circle, and $\mathbb{R} \not \simeq S^1 \times \mathbb{Z}$, for connectedness reasons alone...

As to your question with a continuous section, [this paper](https://www.unav.edu/documents/14434042/14551839/2016_Cross+and+splitting_JMAA.pdf/ebc4a302-94d2-56db-61dc-d6a9c9358d0f) looks relevant (though it's only for Abelian topological groups).

Comment: But in this case there is no section $G/H \to G$.

Comment: @Downvoter: this was an answer to the original question, without the condition that $\sigma$ is continuous.

Comment: (I didn't downvote, but didn't see that the question had been edited when I left my comment -- sorry @HennoBrandsma !)

Comment: @hunter is `@Downvoter` a valid mention? Just wondering...

Comment: I'm downvoting because (1) the counterexample is invalid as mentioned by @hunter and (2) the paper does not answer the question as well. Note that $H$ **is not** assumed to be normal (there is no extension here) and we are looking for homeomorphism, not topological group isomorphism (which is not valid in the context of non-normal subgroup).

Comment: @hunter I don't see any edit in the history that would explain the (2) issue.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma "@Downvoter" doesn't do anything.